# Testing Backbone View when collections fetch success callback calls render

Tags: testing, backbone.js, jasmine, backbone-views, sinon

I am using Jasmine and Sinon to test my Backbone application but I am running in to some trouble. I am attempting to test that render gets called when my view is initialized

I have the following View:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#myElement',
    initialize : function() {
        var that = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            error : function() {
                alert("error!");
            },
            success : function() {
                that.render();
            }
        });
    },

    render : function() {
        this.collection.each(this.renderItem);
    }

    ...
```

My test

```
it('Should call render when view is instantiated', function(){          
                spyOn(MyView.prototype, 'render');
                var myCollection = new MyCollection();
                this.view = new MyView({collection: myCollection});
                expect(MyView.prototype.render).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

The problem is that the expect() gets called before the success callback of my fetch has been executed. What is the best way to resolve this?

Comment: Why don't you just put something like an alert or console.log in your render method?

Comment: I am writing an automated test suite. In future I would like to follow Test Driven Development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem here is that you test 2 things, the view and the collection. You should stub the collection and just test the view:

```
sinon.stub(myCollection, 'fetch').yieldsTo('success') // will immediately call the success methode
sinon.stub(myCollection, 'each').callsArg(0) // will immediately call this.renderItem
```

Also its not a good idea to spy on the class you wanna test. In your case you should test that the innerHTMl of your view has changed as expected after `this.renderItem` was called

Comment: Thank you for both the answer and the advice, very helpful! I realize that this is another question entirely, but if my renderItem method then instantiates a new view, how do I stub that? I am using requirejs. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you ask this in a new question please.